# Loading jQuery with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

Like most of us know, jQuery gets loaded/"activated" on page load but if you bring content via AJAX code requires few modifications or restart in most cases.

**I would like to make FitVids inside Magnific popup to work in AJAX loaded content.** All attemps with this has been failed while I successfully repaired Bootstrap tooltips and few other minor things.

---

**Fitvids inside main.js**

```
(function( $ ) {

  "use strict";

  $.fn.fitVids = function( options ) {
    var settings = {
      customSelector: null,
      ignore: null,
    };

    if(!document.getElementById('fit-vids-style')) {
      // appendStyles: https://github.com/toddmotto/fluidvids/blob/master/dist/fluidvids.js
      var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var css = '.fluid-width-video-wrapper{width:100%;position:relative;padding:0;}.fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe,.fluid-width-video-wrapper object,.fluid-width-video-wrapper embed {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;}';
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = '<p>x</p><style id="fit-vids-style">' + css + '</style>';
      head.appendChild(div.childNodes[1]);
    }

    if ( options ) {
      $.extend( settings, options );
    }

    return this.each(function(){
      var selectors = [
        "iframe[src*='player.vimeo.com']",
        "iframe[src*='youtube.com']",
        "iframe[src*='youtube-nocookie.com']",
        "iframe[src*='kickstarter.com'][src*='video.html']",
        "object",
        "embed"
      ];

      if (settings.customSelector) {
        selectors.push(settings.customSelector);
      }

      var ignoreList = '.fitvidsignore';

      if(settings.ignore) {
        ignoreList = ignoreList + ', ' + settings.ignore;
      }

      var $allVideos = $(this).find(selectors.join(','));
      $allVideos = $allVideos.not("object object"); // SwfObj conflict patch
      $allVideos = $allVideos.not(ignoreList); // Disable FitVids on this video.

      $allVideos.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.parents(ignoreList).length > 0) {
          return; // Disable FitVids on this video.
        }
        if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'embed' && $this.parent('object').length || $this.parent('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').length) { return; }
        if ((!$this.css('height') && !$this.css('width')) && (isNaN($this.attr('height')) || isNaN($this.attr('width'))))
        {
          $this.attr('height', 9);
          $this.attr('width', 16);
        }
        var height = ( this.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'object' || ($this.attr('height') && !isNaN(parseInt($this.attr('height'), 10))) ) ? parseInt($this.attr('height'), 10) : $this.height(),
            width = !isNaN(parseInt($this.attr('width'), 10)) ? parseInt($this.attr('width'), 10) : $this.width(),
            aspectRatio = height / width;
        if(!$this.attr('id')){
          var videoID = 'fitvid' + Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);
          $this.attr('id', videoID);
        }
        $this.wrap('<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper"></div>').parent('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').css('padding-top', (aspectRatio * 100)+"%");
        $this.removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
      });
    });
  };
// Works with either jQuery or Zepto
})( window.jQuery || window.Zepto );
;
```

**Some extra Fitvids + popup in main.js**

```
jQuery(document).find('.property-video-popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'iframe'
});
```

**HTML that triggers popup**

```
<a href=" video URL " class="property-video-popup"> Icon, text, tooltip etc </a>
```

**It seems that I was wrong about popup - it's separate min.js file. I managed to unminify it but I should warn you - it's rather long. There's character limit, I was forced to cut some off.. Let me know if there's something important that's missing!**

```
(function(e) {
    var t, n, i, o, r, a, s, l = "Close",
        c = "BeforeClose",
        d = "AfterClose",
        u = "BeforeAppend",
        p = "MarkupParse",
        f = "Open",
        m = "Change",
        g = "mfp",
        h = "." + g,
        v = "mfp-ready",
        C = "mfp-removing",
        y = "mfp-prevent-close",
        w = function() {}, b = !! window.jQuery,
        I = e(window),
        x = function(e, n) {
            t.ev.on(g + e + h, n)
        }, k = function(t, n, i, o) {
            var r = document.createElement("div");
            return r.className = "mfp-" + t, i && (r.innerHTML = i), o ? n && n.appendChild(r) : (r = e(r), n && r.appendTo(n)), r
        }, T = function(n, i) {
            t.ev.triggerHandler(g + n, i), t.st.callbacks && (n = n.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + n.slice(1), t.st.callbacks[n] && t.st.callbacks[n].apply(t, e.isArray(i) ? i : [i]))
        }, E = function(n) {
            return n === s && t.currTemplate.closeBtn || (t.currTemplate.closeBtn = e(t.st.closeMarkup.replace("%title%", t.st.tClose)), s = n), t.currTemplate.closeBtn
        }, _ = function() {
            e.magnificPopup.instance || (t = new w, t.init(), e.magnificPopup.instance = t)
        }, S = function() {
            var e = document.createElement("p").style,
                t = ["ms", "O", "Moz", "Webkit"];
            if (void 0 !== e.transition) return !0;
            for (; t.length;)
                if (t.pop() + "Transition" in e) return !0;
            return !1
        };
    w.prototype = {
        constructor: w,
        init: function() {
            var n = navigator.appVersion;
            t.isIE7 = -1 !== n.indexOf("MSIE 7."), t.isIE8 = -1 !== n.indexOf("MSIE 8."), t.isLowIE = t.isIE7 || t.isIE8, t.isAndroid = /android/gi.test(n), t.isIOS = /iphone|ipad|ipod/gi.test(n), t.supportsTransition = S(), t.probablyMobile = t.isAndroid || t.isIOS || /(Opera Mini)|Kindle|webOS|BlackBerry|(Opera Mobi)|(Windows Phone)|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent), o = e(document), t.popupsCache = {}
        },
        open: function(n) {
            i || (i = e(document.body));
            var r;
            if (n.isObj === !1) {
                t.items = n.items.toArray(), t.index = 0;
                var s, l = n.items;
                for (r = 0; l.length > r; r++)
                    if (s = l[r], s.parsed && (s = s.el[0]), s === n.el[0]) {
                        t.index = r;
                        break
                    }
            } else t.items = e.isArray(n.items) ? n.items : [n.items], t.index = n.index || 0; if (t.isOpen) return t.updateItemHTML(), void 0;
            t.types = [], a = "", t.ev = n.mainEl && n.mainEl.length ? n.mainEl.eq(0) : o, n.key ? (t.popupsCache[n.key] || (t.popupsCache[n.key] = {}), t.currTemplate = t.popupsCache[n.key]) : t.currTemplate = {}, t.st = e.extend(!0, {}, e.magnificPopup.defaults, n), t.fixedContentPos = "auto" === t.st.fixedContentPos ? !t.probablyMobile : t.st.fixedContentPos, t.st.modal && (t.st.closeOnContentClick = !1, t.st.closeOnBgClick = !1, t.st.showCloseBtn = !1, t.st.enableEscapeKey = !1), t.bgOverlay || (t.bgOverlay = k("bg").on("click" + h, function() {
                t.close()
            }), t.wrap = k("wrap").attr("tabindex", -1).on("click" + h, function(e) {
                t._checkIfClose(e.target) && t.close()
            }), t.container = k("container", t.wrap)), t.contentContainer = k("content"), t.st.preloader && (t.preloader = k("preloader", t.container, t.st.tLoading));
            var c = e.magnificPopup.modules;
            for (r = 0; c.length > r; r++) {
                var d = c[r];
                d = d.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + d.slice(1), t["init" + d].call(t)
            }
            T("BeforeOpen"), t.st.showCloseBtn && (t.st.closeBtnInside ? (x(p, function(e, t, n, i) {
                n.close_replaceWith = E(i.type)
            }), a += " mfp-close-btn-in") : t.wrap.append(E())), t.st.alignTop && (a += " mfp-align-top"), t.fixedContentPos ? t.wrap.css({
                overflow: t.st.overflowY,
                overflowX: "hidden",
                overflowY: t.st.overflowY
            }) : t.wrap.css({
                top: I.scrollTop(),
                position: "absolute"
            }), (t.st.fixedBgPos === !1 || "auto" === t.st.fixedBgPos && !t.fixedContentPos) && t.bgOverlay.css({
                height: o.height(),
                position: "absolute"
            }), t.st.enableEscapeKey && o.on("keyup" + h, function(e) {
                27 === e.keyCode && t.close()
            }), I.on("resize" + h, function() {
                t.updateSize()
            }), t.st.closeOnContentClick || (a += " mfp-auto-cursor"), a && t.wrap.addClass(a);
            var u = t.wH = I.height(),
                m = {};
            if (t.fixedContentPos && t._hasScrollBar(u)) {
                var g = t._getScrollbarSize();
                g && (m.marginRight = g)
            }
            t.fixedContentPos && (t.isIE7 ? e("body, html").css("overflow", "hidden") : m.overflow = "hidden");
            var C = t.st.mainClass;
            return t.isIE7 && (C += " mfp-ie7"), C && t._addClassToMFP(C), t.updateItemHTML(), T("BuildControls"), e("html").css(m), t.bgOverlay.add(t.wrap).prependTo(t.st.prependTo || i), t._lastFocusedEl = document.activeElement, setTimeout(function() {
                t.content ? (t._addClassToMFP(v), t._setFocus()) : t.bgOverlay.addClass(v), o.on("focusin" + h, t._onFocusIn)
            }, 16), t.isOpen = !0, t.updateSize(u), T(f), n
        },
        close: function() {
            t.isOpen && (T(c), t.isOpen = !1, t.st.removalDelay && !t.isLowIE && t.supportsTransition ? (t._addClassToMFP(C), setTimeout(function() {
                t._close()
            }, t.st.removalDelay)) : t._close())
        },
        _close: function() {
            T(l);
            var n = C + " " + v + " ";
            if (t.bgOverlay.detach(), t.wrap.detach(), t.container.empty(), t.st.mainClass && (n += t.st.mainClass + " "), t._removeClassFromMFP(n), t.fixedContentPos) {
                var i = {
                    marginRight: ""
                };
                t.isIE7 ? e("body, html").css("overflow", "") : i.overflow = "", e("html").css(i)
            }
            o.off("keyup" + h + " focusin" + h), t.ev.off(h), t.wrap.attr("class", "mfp-wrap").removeAttr("style"), t.bgOverlay.attr("class", "mfp-bg"), t.container.attr("class", "mfp-container"), !t.st.showCloseBtn || t.st.closeBtnInside && t.currTemplate[t.currItem.type] !== !0 || t.currTemplate.closeBtn && t.currTemplate.closeBtn.detach(), t._lastFocusedEl && e(t._lastFocusedEl).focus(), t.currItem = null, t.content = null, t.currTemplate = null, t.prevHeight = 0, T(d)
        },
        updateSize: function(e) {
            if (t.isIOS) {
                var n = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth,
                    i = window.innerHeight * n;
                t.wrap.css("height", i), t.wH = i
            } else t.wH = e || I.height();
            t.fixedContentPos || t.wrap.css("height", t.wH), T("Resize")
        },
        updateItemHTML: function() {
            var n = t.items[t.index];
            t.contentContainer.detach(), t.content && t.content.detach(), n.parsed || (n = t.parseEl(t.index));
            var i = n.type;
            if (T("BeforeChange", [t.currItem ? t.currItem.type : "", i]), t.currItem = n, !t.currTemplate[i]) {
                var o = t.st[i] ? t.st[i].markup : !1;
                T("FirstMarkupParse", o), t.currTemplate[i] = o ? e(o) : !0
            }
            r && r !== n.type && t.container.removeClass("mfp-" + r + "-holder");
            var a = t["get" + i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1)](n, t.currTemplate[i]);
            t.appendContent(a, i), n.preloaded = !0, T(m, n), r = n.type, t.container.prepend(t.contentContainer), T("AfterChange")

                      Character limit!!!!!
```

Comment: Why don't you try writing it as - > `$(document).find('.property-video-popup').magnificPopup({...`

Comment: to make your plugin work with dynamic elements you have to edit the plugin itself. So the other solution would be, when ever a data is loaded dynamically, better destroy the plugin and reinitialize it again.

Comment: @CerlinBoss Thanks for the tip, any suggestions how to do this? Both plugins are included in theme-main.js not as "plugins" themselves.

Comment: i would like to see the data inside `theme-main.js` and respective html.

Comment: @CerlinBoss Is popup's .js very important? Should I include some? Everything else should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a workaround solution.
You can do the following steps to reinitialize the plugin every time your 
ajax is triggered

1. Clone the existing popup links (WITH OUT EVENTS)
2. Delete the original elements
3. Append the cloned items
4. Initialize the plugin again. (Thus plugin will add events to all the newly added elements).

Try running the below code once the ajax is success and the new elements are created.

```
var $popups = jQuery('.property-video-popup');
var $clones = $popups.clone();

$clones.each(function(index,elem){
    var $popup = $popups.eq(index);
    jQuery(elem).insertAfter($popup);
    $popup.remove();
})

jQuery('.property-video-popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'iframe'
});
```

Comment: **You're the real MVP.** Everything went silk smoothly. Thank you, I actually learned something from this. Cheers!